# Background on WP7 icon

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have created an icon for my WP7 application. The icon got a transparent background and the theme on my WP7 device is set to the blue theme. When deployed to the device my icon got a dark gray background instead of the blue from the theme.

Any ideas how to adopt the theme background color as background to the application icon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Icons used for tiles support transparency but those used in the application list don't - disappointingly.

Comment: OK, damn! Do you have any insight if this is planned in next release?

Comment: No insight but I hope it comes in a future release too though

Comment: I noticed this too as a Tile it means you get Accent Colour consitency for the application tile, but not for the app list, even some Microsoft examples have the blue colour as the app list icon, even though it will look odd when the accent colour is changed.

Comment: The solutions is to not attempt to use the accent color in the app icon. t least, for now.

Comment: For future references, this is fixed in Mango (7.1) release.