# Match ApplicationIcon.jpg accent color

Tags: windows-phone-7

This is a simple question, but I can't seem to find a definite answer to this.

How do I set my Application Icon (the one that appears in the menu)

[image]

to one that matches the accent color? Currently the only way is to overwrite ApplicationIcon.jpg, but jpgs do not have transparency

**Edit:**

This is what I used to get it to work. Copy the .png file over, then rename it to .jpg. It has to be exactly the same name or you will get an error 2 xap packaging failed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a PNG image instead. Any transparent background will use the phone accent colour. See the discussion here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/521c8379-d1a7-44d1-825f-377b68e9ee59/

Comment: PNG is supported from a Mango. In 7.0 transparency in png getting gray, not accent

Comment: @Ku6opr - Transparency is/was supported in 7.0 for accent colours. I've used it a few times.

Comment: @keyboardP - Nop, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807200/background-on-wp7-icon

Comment: @Ku6opr - Sorry, I was thinking of the actual icon on the home screen. Should've read more carefully :)